# How can I hide directory listing for hacker

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

My site build with Magento 1.9.3.4.
someone sends me a mail with an attached image which is my listed directory. My question is how they fetch this. Did any setting to avoid this type of access.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hiding directory listing is quite simply adding below line to **.htaccess**:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

This is normally the case for public facing folders like media where users will need access for product images however you still do not want them listing files when accessing **domain.com/media**

For many folders within magento there should already be **.htaccess** set up for which should not have public access. This will then just show the folder as Forbidden when browsed e.g. **/var** driectory:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Check your **.htaccess** are all present similar to magento 1 base code.

Comment: What is the directory you got listed? I have improved my explanation. Media needs access but not listing the later completely blocks access to files within that folder e.g. var

Comment: That is looking better i was just looking at all your var directory cached configs and then you blocked that atleast.

Comment: images can't load if I put htaccess on skin folder.

Comment: Yeah that's what i said in the answer. Use the Option All -indexes on media. There should already be a htaccess present with this in there however. But yeah dont deny access on folders like media

Comment: @PratikKamani did you fix this?

Comment: No. I have added it. But style and CSS do not load after put htaccess on skin folder.

Comment: .htaccess for media should be like so: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/media/.htaccess

Comment: I dont' think skin folder has one in default magento 1.9 however but could add Options All -Indexes to it and it should make it non browseable atleast and should still work fine.

Comment: Sorry i seem to kept getting skin and media mixed up but similar really both are public facing as that is images in media and your theme files so need to be accessible. Nothing should be in skin that you need to hide anyway however.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, below points can be considered of the hacking possibilities.

1. Few of the security patches are not installed : https://www.magereport.com/scan/?s=https://www.yourshop.com/
2. Check the proper folder permissions, maintain strong passwords and reset all old/previous settings.
3. Contact your hosting provider on what are the possibilities for causing this. they may have clear tracking on ftp ssh/ftp log-ins with ip's.

Hope this helps.